# int*float accuracy

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

I know about differences between number representations but here is something that I would like someone to explain.
we see that value of float t is as it is, and I wonder why f is not equal to 2+t (as mathematically should be) but there is that little, little error [for me it is quite big in fact!].

is this error introduced by int*float multiplication?

[image]

Comment: Why float, rather than double?

Comment: it is intentionally Patricia

Comment: I asked because the normal problem with using float, rather than double, is unacceptably large rounding error, and your comment "for me it is quite big in fact!" suggests that is the situation. Also, safely using float generally requires really careful numerical analysis, and the question suggests that has not been done.

Comment: again it is intention, example, exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, addition or multiplication of a value with integer type with a value of floating-point type is performed by first converting the integer to floating-point and then by performing the arithmetic operation. If the integer value cannot be exactly represented in the floating-point format, then error is introduced even before the operation is performed. With the small integers in your example, this is not an issue.

The arithmetic operation will introduce error if the exact mathematical result is not representable in the floating-point type. There are two ways in which the results might not be representable:

- One is that the number of bits (or digits generally, when not using binary floating-point) needed to represent the significand (fraction portion) do not fit in the floating-point format.
- Another is that the magnitude of the result exceeds the range of the floating-point format, resulting in overflow or underflow.

Your examples do not approach the magnitudes where overflow or underflow occur, so I will not discuss them here.

Assuming you are using IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point, which is commonly used for `float` in C implementations, the significand is 24 bits. So anytime you perform an operation whose result requires more than 24 bits to represent, you get an error. This 24-bit span is measured from the highest set bit in a number to its lowest set bit.

For example, 1111.11111111111111111111<sub>2</sub> requires 24 bits to represent. If you add 10000<sub>2</sub> to it, the exact mathematical result is 11111.11111111111111111111<sub>2</sub>. This requires 25 bits, so it does not fit, so the floating-point implementation must round the exact mathematical result to a representable result. (In the common round-to-nearest mode with this particular value, it rounds the low bit up, causing a carry through all the bits, producing 100000<sub>2</sub>.)

Now you can get some sense of what operations will have errors. If you add two numbers of different magnitudes, some of the low bits of the smaller number will be “pushed out” of the result. If any of those bits are not zero, then information is lost, an error occurs. Additionally, the result might cross a power-of-two boundary, where its highest bit is higher than the highest bit of either of the input values. This pushes another bit out of the significand. For example, if we add 1000 to 1111.11111111111111111111<sub>2</sub>, the exact mathematical result is 10111.11111111111111111111<sub>2</sub>. This requires 25 bits, so the low bit is rounded, producing 11000<sub>2</sub>.

Suppose you have two numbers that require *a* and *b* bits in their significands. When you multiply them, the exact mathematical result requires *a*+*b*–1 or *a*+*b* bits, depending on whether there is a “carry” that produces a new high bit. For example, 11<sub>2</sub>•111<sub>2</sub> = 10101<sub>2</sub>, two bits times three bits produces five bits. Or 1.001<sub>2</sub>•1.01<sub>2</sub> = 1.01101<sub>2</sub>, four bits times three bits produces six bits. So multiplications by integers can produce rounding errors.

Multiplying by powers of two never produces rounding errors in this way, although it can cause overflow or underflow.

Comment: Thank you. what we should do then to achieve best accuracy when dealing with numbers, calculations?

Comment: @cf16: That is an open-ended question. There is a lot of literature about using floating point operations. Best practices depend on context; there are various techniques for specific situations. Generally, and very roughly, `double` is about the same cost as `float` on modern processors when you are not doing high volumes of calculations, so use `double` for most floating point. And study floating point to learn how it works and what errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of floating-point errors in floats. Since floats can only contain a certain number of binary digits, they cannot be completely accurate, so you get numbers that are not quite exact when doing calculations with them.

Comment: yes, sure, but what can you say about float+int for example? this one will be always exact?

Comment: float+int will be as exact as the float is. For example, if you have a float that is 2.4 and an int that is 1 adding them will always be 3.4, but if your float is supposed to be 2.4 and it is actually 2.39999 (because you got it through some calculation) the result will be 3.3999. It is only when dividing/multiplying such that the answer has many digits after the decimal place that floating-point errors occur.

Comment: I am afraid this is not true

Comment: You are right. If the float has, ever has had, or is a result of a calculation from a number that had a decimal value, it is prone to this error.

Comment: I think I have seen some example with even only addition and such errors occurred, I will look for this

Comment: @cf16 Try 3.3. In Java, I got 3.2999999523162841796875 before adding one, 4.30000019073486328125 after.

Comment: thats Java xD can be! and one of 1000 reasons why I prefer our C/C++

Comment: @cf16 I don't understand your comment. Java requires the use of IEEE 754 32-bit binary for its float type. I used it for this test because I happen to know an easy way to get the exact value printed, necessary to see the rounding difference when starting with short decimal fractions.